# C# - sorting a rectangular array by selected columns

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array

Please how do I sort the following array (in C#) by the second column desc, then by the first column asc (and then insert the resulting rank in the third column which I guess might be a separate question). 
I'm a beginner in C#, I have spent quite some time looking for an answer to this seemingly simple question, but I couldn't find any approach that would work for me. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
int[,] myArray = new int[5, 4]
{
   {1, 7, 0, 0} ,
   {2, 12, 0, 0} ,
   {3, 15, 0, 0} ,
   {4, 7, 0, 0} ,
   {5, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a multidimensional array, there isn’t really a concept of “rows”. All values are just in the same relation to another. That’s why sorting multidimensional arrays is somewhat tricky.

It gets easier when you use [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), basically arrays of arrays. Your array would look like this:

```
int[][] myJaggedArray = new int[][]
{
   new int[] { 1, 7, 0, 0 },
   new int[] { 2, 12, 0, 0 },
   new int[] { 3, 15, 0, 0 },
   new int[] { 4, 7, 0, 0 },
   new int[] { 5, 1, 0, 0 },
};
```

You can also convert your multidimensional array into a jagged array, doing something like this:

```
int[][] myJaggedArray = new int[myArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1][];
for(int i = 0; i < myJaggedArray.Length; i++)
    myJaggedArray[i] = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).Select(k => myArray[i,k]).ToArray();
```

Once you have a jagged array, sorting it is really easy using LINQ:

```
var result = myJaggedArray
    .OrderBy(row => row[1])
    .ThenBy(row => row[0])
    .Select((row, idx) =>
    {
        row[2] = idx;
        return row;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: works perfectly (I just replaced the OrderBy with OrderByDescending), thanks a lot for the solution and for the explanation - I obviously misunderstood the concept of rectangular arrays